# Best place to render html in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have documents stored in a tree structure in sql server , I have written two different approaches to retrieving them.  The first is to return JSON from the controller and use javascript / jQuery to parse the it  and render the html tree structure.  The second method I have is to render the markup on the server and return as HTML.  What method is the most efficient,scalable,ect.. and why.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jquery templates and specify your markup in a template. Pass your JSON datasource to it and you will have what you need. This way you won't need to parse anything, nor will you need to render your HTML code on the server.